# How to unlock selected files from root?

Tags: files

I am trying to unlock files from my root to a admin account. I've tried by going into the account and moving the files into it, but when I go to the account its all locked. And when I do `CTRL+A` and it selects all of the files. And then I right click on one file because all of then are selected, then I change the permissions to my admin account. The folders are unlocked but the folders inside them aren't.

Is there a way to unlock them *all*?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Things owned by root are owned by root for a reason. What are you trying to accomplish exactly?

Answer (score 4):

When you change the permissions of the folder, use 'Change Permissions for Enclosed Files' or 'Apply Permissions to Enclosed Files' button:

[image: permssions]

---

Or just use `chmod` with the `-R` option. You can use the table on [this](http://ss64.com/bash/chmod.html) page:

[image: chmod]

```
chmod -R 757 /PATH/TO/FOLDER
```

or you can change the owner with `chown` - see [here](http://ss64.com/bash/chown.html):

```
chown -R USERNAME:USERNAME /PATH/TO/FOLDER
```